# Understanding Bohr's response to a 1930 Einstein thought experiment that challenged the uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, einstein

**Structure of this post**

I want to better understand how Bohr responded to Einstein's 1930 attempt to demonstrate that quantum mechanics was inherently contradictory under the Copenhagen interpretation.

This post is long because I really wanted to be clear in what I think Einstein and Bohr said in setting up my question. But I've put a brief summary of problem and question at the top with all the nitty-gritty details underneath.

**Summary of problem and question**

*Issue.* Einstein proposed an experiment in 1930 that contradicted energy-time uncertainty. If you set it up so a box of light opened for a brief period $ \Delta t $ (meaning you know when the even happened within a fixed time-interval) and a photon escaped, by measuring the mass of the box afterwards, you could find the energy $ E = m c^2$ exactly, i.e. $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$ - contravening $\Delta E \Delta t > h$.

*Bohr solution.* Bohr rebuts this by envisaging what the experiment would look like. He pictures a box hanging from a spring, with a pointer aligned against a scale. After the photon escapes, the box starts oscillating. By adding weights we can centre the box against the original position of the scale, so finding the mass lost with arbitrary accuracy.

The process of measuring the mass by looking at a scale means we are working to an accuracy determined by an uncertainty in position $\Delta q$. The better we know this, the worse we know the momentum of the box according to $\Delta p > h/\Delta q$. By linking the uncertainty in mass with the uncertainty in momentum, Bohr pupports to show that to minimise the uncertainty in position $\Delta q$ we must maximise the length of time $T$ over which we measure the mass of the box.

In his final move, he notes that the time interval in the box's reference frame is different to that in the laboratory rest frame since the box is moving in a gravitational field. The uncertainty in the time interval - $\Delta T$ - is a function of $\Delta q$. By putting all this together, Bohr reproduces the energy time uncertainty relation:
$$
\Delta E \Delta T > h.
$$
Phew for Copenhagen.

*My big issue with this.* I have a lot of issues with this derivation, but first and foremost among them is: Einstein was concerned with the length of time the box was open $\Delta t$ and our ability to measure the energy of the associated photon escaping the box to an arbitrary accuracy.

Bohr introduces a totally different time-scale - that of the mass measurement (what I've called $T$ to differentiate it) and then derives the energy-time uncertainty for the measurement of that.

What on earth is the relationship between the time interval Bohr introduces and what Einstein was taking about.

This is driving me nuts - as the convoluted post below will attest. Please help!

**The above question described out in lots of gory detail**

Einstein fundamentally disliked the prevailing Copenhagen interpretation of QM that emerged in the 20s and 30s. A couple of times, he devised thought experiments to try and illustrate that uncertainty - a fundamental tenet of QM - was violated. The below is his most successful attempt - taking Bohr a fretful night to try and rebuke it (which he did, see below).

What Einstein did was try and show that you could measure the energy of something perfectly within a fixed time period - violating the energy-time uncertainty principle $\Delta E \Delta t > h$ (I'll ignore factors of $4\pi$ in the following for convenience).

**What Einstein said to Bohr**

- Imagine a box with photons bouncing around in it (perfectly reflective walls etc; all that usual thought experiment / idealisation stuff).
- The box contains a clock to keep an eye on the time.
- For a length of time $\Delta t$ - as determined by the clock - a hole in the box is opened and a photon flies out.
- We know to within a fixed time-scale how long the box is open - $\Delta t$ - i.e. the time-window in which we are attempting to calculate the energy of the photon.
- According to the indeterminacy principle, our knowledge of the energy of the photon should be bounded by $\Delta E > h / \Delta t$ .
- What Einstein aimed to demonstrate was that it *was* possible to calculate the energy as precisely as you like, i.e. $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$ - in violation of Heisenberg.
- He 'showed' this by noting that $\Delta E = \Delta m c^2$. By simply weighing the box (which we can do at our leisure so do it as accurately as possible) we can infer the energy change as the difference in two exactly known masses, meaning $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$ while the time interval is fixed.
- This obviously violates uncertainty.

**Bohr's reply**

To rebut this, Bohr went into a lot more detail about the box and how you'd actually go about carrying out the thought experiment.

- He pictured the weighing apparatus as follows: the box is attached to an undamped spring (undamped so energy, i.e. mass, is not lost) and lined up against a scale to measure its mass.
- After the photon is released, the box will be oscillating; we can add smaller and smaller weights to the box to get it back to the zero on the scale - i.e. where it will be (almost) at rest. The masses we add equals the mass lost (and so gives us the energy change perfectly, according to Einstein).

Now I will attempt to relate Bohr's version of his reply as he later told it in 1949, see [here](https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/dk/bohr.htm). I'm not saying I agree with this - and if it's obtuse it's because Bohr is very brief in his discussion.

1. The box's mass can be measured with any accuracy $\Delta m$ by addition of suitable loads. To know we've added the correct masses we must line the box up at the zero of the aligned scale. In other words, to assess the mass we must limit uncertainty in the measurement of position of the box $\Delta q$.
2. This will require smaller and smaller masses to be added over a long time-interval I'll denote $T$,which Bohr calls the "interval of the balancing procedure" (that this interval is 'long' is shown below).
3. Through the position-momentum uncertainty relation, measuring the position of the box up to some uncertainty $\Delta q$ places a lower bound on our knowledge of the momentum of the box: $\Delta p > h/\Delta q$.
4. The residual uncertainty in our knowledge of the mass ($\Delta m$) will leave the box moving slightly (since the spring system is out of equilibrium unless $\Delta m = 0$, which would require an infinite precision in the experiment which is impossible).
5. Bohr then states that the "latitude" in momentum will "obviously" be smaller than the total impulse given by the force of gravity to a body of mass $\Delta m$, leading to:
   $$
   \Delta p < gT \Delta m.
   $$
6. So we have $\Delta p < gT \Delta m $ and $\Delta p > h/\Delta q$. Taking the left equation as an equality we can put these together to show: $\Delta m > \frac{h}{gT\Delta q}$.
7. What this shows is that in order to render our reading of the mass very accurate - which necessitates us minimising the uncertainty in the measurement of $q$, i.e. $\Delta q \rightarrow 0$ - then we need to perform the weight measurement over a very long time interval: $T \rightarrow \infty $.

The following is Bohr's coup-de-grâce:

7. A clock displaced by an amount $\Delta q$ will change its rate in such a way that its reading over a time interval $\Delta T$ will differ by an amount:
   $$
   \frac{\Delta T}{T} = \frac{g \Delta q}{c^2}.
   $$
8. This imposes a limit on the accuracy of the time interval measurement according to: $\Delta T = Tg\Delta q/c^2$, which upon combining with the equation derived above relating position and mass uncertainty (point 6) results in:
   $$
   \Delta mc^2 \Delta T > h.
   $$

In other words, we re-derive time-energy uncertainty and so there is no issue. As Bohr stated in 1949: "Consequently, a use of the apparatus as a means of accurately measuring the energy of the photon will prevent us from controlling the moment of its escape."

**My question (again)**

I have so many questions about this I could write probably ten. But I'll keep it to one clear and simple one: assuming no other issues with the above, it seems to me that Bohr has related uncertainty in our knowledge over the time interval that the weighing procedure is carried out $\Delta T$, with uncertainty in the mass of the box.

So he has shown that, for an oscillating box, we cannot measure the energy of the box over a given time $T$ to greater than an accuracy of $\Delta T \Delta E > h$. This is just a statement of the uncertainty principle.

But the critical time here is surely the length of time the box is open, not the time over which we measure the energy of the box? How is Bohr happy with this justification; and how did Einstein not pick him up on introducing a totally different time interval?

Comment: I would also like to understand this better. My hunch actually is: the use of time-delation is not necessary to proof time-Energy uncertanty (it can't be necessary, otherwise we would have to use GR time all the time in QM which as far as a see is not happening). The use of GR here is probably an alternative route which was choosen by Bohr as  a 'belly punch' in the sense of defeating Einstein with his own weapons.